# Using aggregate function value again in the query

Tags: mysql, jpa, count, aggregate-functions

I would like to use the value of count() in the same query inside greatest(). Is there a way to do this?

I tried count(id) as my_count, greatest(my_count, 7) but it gives an error:
 `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'my_count' in 'field list'`
If I use `greatest(count(id), 7)` will it increase the query time?
Also can I do the same in JPA @Query?

Comment: You cannot use aliases from the SELECT within the SELECT, I've got no idea if MySQL optimizes multiple identical COUNT expressions  in a single select, but I'd hope so. When I've been really concerned about needing the same expression twice, I've turned the "main" query into a subquery, and used the alias repeatedly in the wrapping query. Like this: `SELECT my_count, GREATEST(my_count, 7) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS my_count ....) AS mainQ`

Comment: @Uueerdo you really should have posted that as an answer...

Comment: Thank you @Uueerdo. I really appreciate the answer. But is there a way I could do that in JPA? I'm new to it. I'll add the relevant tags in the edited question. My bad

Comment: I don't think there should be any cost in doing `GREATEST(COUNT(*), 7)`. You're not doing anything twice with that.

Comment: @Nick yeah, I just hesitate when I have expressions like "I've no idea".

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS Your problem is a code extension not returning what you expect. Make it clear that your question is about *that error* & ask re your overall goal later in a new post.

Comment: Re "will it increase the query time" If you can't write simple queries you don't need to worry about "query time".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use aliases from a SELECT within the same SELECT, aliases from a subquery's SELECT can be used in an outer query. I'm not sure if MySQL optimizes multiple identical COUNT expressions in a single select, but I'd hope so.

When I've been really concerned about needing the same expression twice, and the possible performance implications of repeating it (or, more often, the impact on readability/maintainablity of repeated lengthy expressions), I've found turning the "main" query into a subquery, and using the alias repeatedly in a wrapping query to be helpful.

In the general form, something like this

`SELECT stuff, long_equation AS r1, long_equation_with_extra_operations AS r2 FROM tables`

becomes

```
SELECT mainQ.*, r1_with_extra_operations AS r2
FROM (SELECT stuff, long_equation AS r1 FROM tables) AS mainQ
```

For this question's particular case, the following would be the application of the above tactic:

```
SELECT my_count, GREATEST(my_count, 7) 
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS my_count ....) AS mainQ
```

Note: the subquery will obviously have to include any fields used in the "extra operations" portion, so depending on the specifics of the original query  this tactic is not always possible or at least may not be as straightforward to use.

(`GREATEST`, in a SELECT expression, should have very little performance impact; it is the equivalent of `CASE WHEN a IS NULL OR b IS NULL THEN NULL WHEN a > b THEN a ELSE b END`. However, using it in a WHERE or ON clause could hurt performance significantly since MySQL cannot cannot take advantage of indexes on fields in such cases.